# Series object not callable error while plotting

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, arima

I'm trying to plot a curve using matlpotlib, but its giving an error - Series object is not callable,
I am following an article [ARIMA Model - Complete Guide](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/arima-model-time-series-forecasting-python/)

but when i'm trying the given code to plot, its giving me the following error
This is the csv file, I'm working with 
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXaoi.png)

Here is the code:

```
    #Import data
    df = pd.read_csv('SKUs\\ACSO5.csv', names = ['Sales'], header = 0)

    #Original Series
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex = True)
    axes[0, 0].plot(df.Sales);
    axes[0, 0].set_title('Original Series')
    plot_acf(df.Sales, ax = axes[0, 1])

    #1 st Differencing
    axes[1, 0].plot(df.Sales());
    axes[1, 0].set_title('1st Order Differencing')
    plot_acf(df.Sales().dropna(), ax = axes[1, 1])

    # 2 nd Differencing
    axes[2, 0].plot(df.Sales.diff().diff());
    axes[2, 0].set_title('2nd Order Differencing')
    plot_acf(df.Sales.value().diff().dropna(), ax = axes[2, 1])
```

This is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-0e2f61a1832f> in <module>
      8 
      9 # 1st Differencing
---> 10 axes[1, 0].plot(df.Sales()); axes[1, 0].set_title('1st Order Differencing')
     11 plot_acf(df.Sales().dropna(), ax=axes[1, 1])
     12 

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses after `Sales`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
does adding parenthesis after a df.columnname tells python that its a series?